# cv::imshow blocks thread when GUI application runs

Tags: python, c++, qt, opencv

I've been trying to debug this for a while but I'm at wit's end so I'll try to ask this here. I guess I'm just asking for hints on what could cause this.

I have two programs: A C++ back-end that does a lot of computer vision stuff, and a Python front-end that shows a GUI. The GUI is the entry point and starts up the back-end after loading. Currently, the back-end somehow blocks its main thread here:

```
if(image.size() != getImageSize()) {
    cv::imshow("projectorDisplay",display_image(cv::Rect(0,0,getImageSize().width,getImageSize().height)));
} else {
    cv::imshow("projectorDisplay",display_image); //Thread blocks at this line.
}
cv::waitKey(10);
```

It's meant to display display_image on a projector that's connected to the computer. The image doesn't get displayed, and the thread blocks so the back-end doesn't get any further. The window is created in the constructor of the same class as follows:

```
cv::namedWindow("projectorDisplay",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
cv::moveWindow("projectorDisplay",2000,0); //Move the window to the projector screen. TODO: Hard-coded value.
cv::setWindowProperty("projectorDisplay",CV_WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN); //Make fullscreen.
cv::waitKey(50);
```

But here's the strange part that led me to think this is a very difficult bug: **When I run the back-end without the GUI, it works fine.** The GUI is a fairly simple Qt-based application in Python that communicates commands via local sockets to the back-end. It should be completely separate; it's even written in a script-language, and runs also when the back-end is not present (the back-end is a plug-in).

Some other things I noticed while debugging:

- This bug is only on Windows. At least, it doesn't occur in Ubuntu.
- When I add `cv::imshow("projectorDisplay",cv::imread("testimage.png"));` to the constructor, it is displayed properly.
- When I add `cv::imshow("projectorDisplay",cv::imread("testimage.png"));` instead of the line where it otherwise gets blocked, it blocks at the new `imshow` too, so it's not just an issue of a corrupt image.
- The issue remains if I don't make the window full-screen in the constructor.
- When I replace the blocking line with `cv::imshow("projectorDisplay2",display_image)`, a new window is created and the image is displayed correctly.
- When I change the `CV_WINDOW_NORMAL` flag to `CV_WINDOW_OPENGL` in the constructor, the back-end crashes immediately at launch.

Does anyone have an idea of what could cause such a thing and where I should look to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is disturbingly simple; recompiling opencv without QT fixes the problem.